# Calling a stored procedure from Sql server 2008 to return value for android login validate

Tags: android, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with a stored procedure that selects two columns(username,password) to return a value to validate a users login on a android login page. How do I call the stored procedure to return a value and compare it to the username and password edittextbox.

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
USE [Login_DB]
GO
 StoredProcedure [dbo].[spLoginvalidate]    Script Date: 03/13/2013 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spLoginvalidate]
(
@User_ID varchar(50),
@Password varchar(20),
@Outres int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
set @Outres= (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Login
WHERE  User_ID=@User_ID and Password=@Password
and CAST (Password as varbinary(20))=CAST (@Password AS varbinary(20))) 
--WHERE CAST(Password AS varbinary(15)) = CAST(@Password AS varbinary(15))
if(@Outres=1)
begin
set @Outres=1
end
else
begin
set @outres=0
end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Here is my code:

```
class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
* Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
* */
Context context;
```

String email,password;

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();

}


protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

       // Building Parameters
       // Send your email and password as the following parameters
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));

       String url = "http://192.168.0.57:8000/Service1.svc/rest/Login";
       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

       // This is the entire response like the JSON data you sent me
       JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params, context);

       // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
       // CHECK LOGCAT IF YOU GET ANY RESPONSE FROM SERVER
       Log.d("Results: ", json.toString());

       try {
             // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
             JSONObject validateobject = json.getJSONObject("Details");

             @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Boolean isloggedin = validateobject.getBoolean("Validat");

             // THATS THE BOOLEAN THAT WILL INDICATE IF VALID LOGIN

             // DO NOT MAKE CHANGES TO GUI ON THIS THREAD E.G. TOAST ETC
             // USE THE ON POST EXECUTE BELOW ELSE THE APPLICATION WILL CRASH

       } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;
}

/**
* After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
* **/


}
```

Comment: please do some research before you start asking questions.Use the search function.You need a middle tier to communicate with the db .. like WebService or REST API.Such broad questions are not invited on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to directly talk to your databse from your app because any user could gain access to your database once they have the app.

Your best bet is to set up a WebService which can call your stored procedure on your DataBase and return the result to your Android code.

This can be done in something like PHP.

Look into PHP communication with SQL and Android communtication with PHP WebServices.

Comment: Alright wil do so , thanx

Comment: @ChristieLouisJones If this is an acceptable answer can you mark this as "Answered" then please?